# Python selenium can not click the button

Tags: python, selenium

Trying to click the button on the page,have ' Unable to locate element' error.
Have tryed find element by id,xpath,link text and always see the same error.
How can I access the button?

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome('\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('http://www.pcpao.org/?pg=http://www.pcpao.org/general.php?strap=153114131800003010')
button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/blockquote/div/p[10]/font/button[1]/font")
button.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page is organized into two frames, the second one has the button you're trying to click (called `bodyFrame`). You should switch to it first and then click the button within it, like so:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://www.pcpao.org/?pg=http://www.pcpao.org/general.php?strap=153114131800003010')

# Switch to frame named 'bodyFrame'
browser.switch_to.frame('bodyFrame')

button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/blockquote/div/p[10]/font/button[1]")
button.click()
```